# Playwright - how to turn off PWDEBUG?

Tags: javascript, typescript, debugging, testing, playwright

I have a simple question.

How to turn off the PWDEBUG on Playwright when running 'npx playwright test'

I have added a $env:PWDEBUG=1 in VS Terminal and all the time the tests are running into debugging mode. I just want the tests to run.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried exiting (not closing but clicking on the trash icon) out of terminal and launching it again?

Answer (score 1):

You can unset the environment variable by the following command

```
$env:PWDEBUG=""
```

this should run the tests in normal mode.

Comment: In addition to this, if you just want to run in debug mode as a once off, use `PWDEBUG=1 npx playwright test`. I find this more convenient to switch between commands in my terminal than constantly setting and unsetting the env var.

Comment: This won't work for Windows users, since they have to either use `$env` or the `set` command in batch to set environment variables. For Linux and MacOS this works yeah.

Comment: Good point, only tried this on MacOS.

Comment: Looks like you can also use the `--debug` flag which is a bit easier to remember: `npx playwright test --debug`